# Interesting trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Find all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\arccos x = 2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$

Now, here is my approach, please state **anything** that is not **correct/fully motivated.**

$\cos 2\theta =2\cos ^2\theta -1$
$\cos ^2\theta =\frac{\cos ^2\theta}{1}=\frac{\cos ^2\theta}{\cos ^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1}{1+\tan ^2\theta }$
$\Rightarrow \cos 2\theta = \frac{2}{1+\tan ^2\theta}-1$

$\cos \arccos x = x = \cos(2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}} ) = \frac{2}{1+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}-1=1+x-1=x. $

Hence, we have shown that $\cos LHS=\cos RHS$ and thus the solutions are given by the intersections of the domains of the functions.

$f(x)=\arccos x \ \ \ \ \ D_{f} = \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: -1\leq x\leq 1 \right \}$
$g(x)=2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}} \ \ \ \ \ D_{f} = \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: x\neq 1 \wedge x\leq 1 \wedge x> -1 \right \}$

Solutions are thus given by:

$D_{f}\cap D_{g}=\left \{ -1< x< 1 \right \}$

Follow up question: Is it enough to show that $\cos LHS = \cos RHS$ and proceed as I've done?

Comment: I think you just need to include 1 in your answer (since it is in the domain of both functions) and also observe that both sides of the equation are in $[0,\pi]$, so that having the same cosine implies that they're equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

By calculating the derivative

$$\left(2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)'=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=(\arccos x)'$$
 and verifying that the two expressions have the same value at $0$ (for example) we conclude that the equality hold for all $x\in(-1,1]$

Comment: Effective Hint my bro. +

Comment: Beautiful, Sami!